# What is the difference between a cue and a lead?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-choice

Say, yesterday, I got an idea in my mind that I had to go shopping this afternoon. And now is 3 pm and I almost forgot about going shopping but when I saw my wallet on the table, it triggered my mind and I remembered to go shopping.

Is it correct to say "**When I looked at my wallet, I remembered to go shopping. So, the wallet acted as a cue**"

or "**When I looked at my wallet, I remembered to go shopping. So, the wallet acted as a lead**"?

**What is the difference between a cue and a lead?**

Comment: Cue anything that excites to action; stimulus.  ///  Lead:  a suggestion or piece of information that helps to direct or guide; tip; clue:   Do these **dictionary definition** help?

Answer (score 1):

The wallet acted as a reminder or prompt, not a cue or lead.

A [cue](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cue) is to take some previously-determined action at a given signal.
It comes from theatre, where your cue is your signal to go onstage, or to start a particular speech or action.
"The actress said, 'I wonder where Horace is?' That was my cue to go on."

A [lead](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lead) is some action or path to follow, to copy.
"Follow my lead" = do as I do, or act in a similar manner.
"The path leads to a gate" …by following the path, you will arrive at the gate.

You could use, "He took $10 from his wallet and handed it to me. That was my cue to go shopping."

Comment: *Lead* can also mean a bit of information helpful in resolving a problem, as in, “The police are working the case hard, but have yet to turn up any leads.” This sense of the word makes it a possible choice in OP’s question.